# Is there a way to prepend to a bash array without writing a function?

Tags: arrays, bash

Start with `arrayA` values below.

```
arrayA=(‘valueA’ ‘valueB’ ‘valueC’)

*…Clever_One_line_Statement_goes_here…*
```

After …Clever_One_line_Statement the `arrayA` has the values....

```
arrayA=(‘’ ‘valueA’ ‘valueB’ ‘valueC’)
```

Comment: You probably don't want "smart" quotes (`‘’`), but normal single quotes (`''`).

Comment: BTW, what's the context for this? If it's performance-sensitive or going to be done in a tight loop, there are faster approaches that require some prep (f/e, initializing your array with high numeric indexes so there's space to add new entries with lower index numbers).

Comment: BTW, the word `shift` in shell is generally used to refer to shifting *left*, removing an item rather than prepending one; I've tried to edit to make the title more clear.

Comment: The context is that the code is doing XML parsing.  Yes I know there are better tool to parse XML and xmllint.  But that is what I got to work with.  XML start with 1 not 0.  I want to avoid the index miss-match between XML and BASH to make it easy to understand and avoid bugs.

Comment: You don't have to insert an empty element to get one-based arrays in Bash, you can just assign to indices directly: `arrayA=([1]='valueA' [2]='valueB')` etc.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the properly quoted parameter expansion:

```
$ arrayA=('valueA' 'valueB' 'valueC')
$ declare -p arrayA
declare -a arrayA=([0]="valueA" [1]="valueB" [2]="valueC")
$ arrayA=('' "${arrayA[@]}")
$ declare -p arrayA
declare -a arrayA=([0]="" [1]="valueA" [2]="valueB" [3]="valueC")
```

Notice that I've used "normal" single quotes (`''`); the "smart" ones you used (`‘’`) would be interpreted literally, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Does not seem to be working.  arrayA=('' "${arrayA[@]}") is what I was looking for.  But it comes out as an array 2 elements long.  When the original was 27 elements long

Comment: @paulhr It should be working fine. If you believe you're seeing otherwise, please post the result of `declare -p arrayA` before and after.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about performance, [the answer by @BenjaminW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54773798/14122) is great. On the other hand, if you're going to do this repeatedly to the same array and need it to be fast, consider making your array sparse, and leaving a broad swatch of unused indexes that you can fill in to add items quickly at the beginning:

```
# Use a larger offset than you'll ever need; here, starting at 10,000
arrayA=( [10000]='valueA' [10001]='valueB' [10002]='valueC' )
arrayIdx=0

# then, to add an empty string at the top of your array, use this one-liner:
arrayA[arrayIdx++]=''
```

Comment: By the way, the assignment also works with `arrayA=( [10000]='valueA' 'valueB' 'valueC' )`.

Answer (score 3):

perl calls this operation "unshift". To implement this as a bash function (requires version 4.4+ for namerefs)

```
$ unshift() { local -n ary=$1; shift; ary=("$@" "${ary[@]}"); }
$ x=(foo bar baz)
$ unshift x "first value" "second value" "third value"
$ declare -p x
declare -a x=([0]="first value" [1]="second value" [2]="third value" [3]="foo" [4]="bar" [5]="baz")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another take.

```
$: declare -a a=( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 )
$: echo "${#a[@]}"
9
$:  echo ${a[1]}
2
$: a=( '' "${a[@]}" )
$: echo "${#a[@]}"
10
$: echo ${a[1]}
1
$: unset a[0]
$: echo "${#a[@]}"
9
$: echo ${a[1]}
1
```

The `unset` removes the bogus cell 0 entirely.
So, short version -

```
$: a=( '' "${a[@]}" )
$: unset a[0]
```

Answer (score -3):

The below line got me what I needed.

```
cellNameArray=('' ${cellNameArray[*]} )
```

Benjamin W. was really close.  Removed the double quotes and replace the '@' with a '*'.

Thanks Benjamin for the idea.

Comment: Use Benjamin's solution. With this version, if you have any elements that contain whitespace, the new array will have different elements. Test with `ary=("first element" "second element"); ary=('' ${ary[*]})` -- now `ary` has **five** elements, not three.

Comment: The double quotes and the `@` are **mandatory** for correct operation, as glenn points out above.

Comment: ... Which is to say, if this worked, your "array" wasn't really an array in the first place, but was instead just a single big string.